# how to use golang exec to download a nvm version

Tags: go, nvm

whenever I run this function let's say with version **14** or any version I get an error of exit with status 3. I would Ideally want a solution that can run on windows, mac, linux. thank you

```
func InstallNodeVersionWithNVM(version string) {
            fmt.Printf("\ninstalling node version: %s", version)
            nodeVersion := version
            
            var cmd *exec.Cmd
            if runtime.GOOS == "windows" {
                // Windows command to install nvm
                cmd = exec.Command("cmd", "/C", "powershell", "-Command", "iex (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/nvm/nvm_install.ps1'); nvm install 14.17.6")
            } else {
                // Unix-like command to install nvm
                cmd = exec.Command("bash", "-l", "-c", ". $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh && nvm install "+version+" && nvm use "+version)
            }
            // Specify the full path to the nvm executable
            cmd.Path = "/bin/bash"
            cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
            cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
        
            // Run the cmd and check for errors
            err := cmd.Run()
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("\n error install node version %s", nodeVersion)
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
        
            fmt.Println(color.HiGreenString("success"), "NVM version:", nodeVersion, "successfully!")
        }
```

Comment: The macOS variant seems to work, at least if `nvm` is installed. For Windows there seems to be no `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/master/nvm/nvm_install.ps1`, so it cannot be downloaded.

Comment: @StephanSchlecht for some reason it wont run on my m1 machine. nvm is already install as well